# Can I inherit a class to provide com-interop to Generics?

Tags: .net, vb.net, com-interop

I have a class that contains a number of public xxx as List(Of someType). This is widely used throughout our code. Unfortunately I also need to provide those lists as ArrayList because we need that same object to be accessible in VBA (Excel specifically).

I am familiar with abstract and override/new, but this would mean changing a *whole lot* of code that's already implemented, and, to my eye, creating a *lot* of extra code (there are maybe 50 of these things) to abstract out the objects when in fact that's the case that's used 99% of the time.

Here's the basic problem...

```
public class cProp
    private Eyes as List(Of Integer)
    public property Eyes as List(Of Integer)
        'get and set that does a lot of work
    end property
    'repeat 50 times
end class
```

Almost all of our code uses cProp, so writing a 50-item abstract base class that has nothing else in it seems like its doing nothing but introduce bugs. So ideally I'd like something like...

```
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
public class dProp
    inherits cProp
    public readonly property **something** Eyes as ArrayList
        'convert List to ArrayList
    end property
end class
```

If such a thing exists, I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: What's the downside of simply adding a load of separate readonly properties EyesArray etc that provide out the existing props as ArrayLists?

Comment: Never expose implementation, COM clients only use interfaces.  System.Collections.IList in this case.  Finding an implementation for it is simple, List<> implements it.

Comment: @tolanj, can I have two properties that differ only in return type? I thought they had to be poly on the *parameters*, especially in COM where the compiler doesn't know the return type?

Comment: @hans hello again!) Can you be more specific? I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. You seem to be saying that List<> would work, but such definitions are invisible in COM. Am I supposed to instead expose a version that uses "As IList"?

Comment: Spell it out, As System.Collections.IList.  And simply return the List object.  Only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. COM does not support generics and calls to generic interfaces or classes (direct or indirect) will result in a `E_NOINTERFACE` error. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what you may **not** do when defining types for interopability:

> - Accessing generic interfaces from COM.
> - Accessing class interfaces for nongeneric classes that derive from generic classes.
> - Generating class interfaces for generic classes. For example, the `_FooBar` interface cannot be generated for the `Foo<Bar>` class.

While your .NET implementation may use generic types, you are only able to expose non-generic versions to COM. Instad of exposing `IEnumerable<int>` or `IList<int>` to COM, let your class interface inherit from [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) instead (or use it as property type). This interface is COM compatible and the generic version implements it, so you can keep type safety on the .NET side and consume the non-generic version from COM.

Comment: Thanks for this. I clearly have a lot of reading to do on interfaces!